# Google Script read data from query

Tags: google-apps-script, stock, yahoo-finance

I create stock table in google sheet. Try to use function when read data from Yahoo Finance. Specially from query service.
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/PFE?modules=summaryDetail%2C
I would like to get the dividendRate data which is Forward Annual Dividend Rate. But now is result ERROR. Could someone help me?
`

```
function YahooDivis(ticker) {
  var ticker = ticker || "PFE";
  ticker = encodeURI(ticker);
  const url = `https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/${ticker}?modules=summaryDetail%2C`;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var chain = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return parseFloat(chain.quotesummary.result[0].dividendRate.raw);
}
```

\

I create function which scrape Trailing Annual Dividend Yield data, but it is not good.
I went for this value in a different way:
`

```
function YahooDivi(ticker) {
  var ticker = ticker || "PFE";
  ticker = encodeURI(ticker);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/" + ticker);
  var chain = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return parseFloat(chain.optionChain.result[0].quote.trailingAnnualDividendRate);
}
```

But is not value when found. I expect Forward Annual Dividend Rate data.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
chain.quotesummary.result[0].dividendRate.raw
chain.optionChain.result[0].quote.trailingAnnualDividendRate
```

To

```
chain.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.dividendYield.raw
chain.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.trailingAnnualDividendRate.raw

9:36:45 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:36:46 AM  Info    0.0336
9:36:46 AM  Info    1.59
9:36:46 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```